# I am getting Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[LinkedList]", variable has type "LinkedList")

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have been given an assignment where I Have to print the content of a LinkedList to screen in the original format, and then sort the list by descending population without using any of the integrated sorting functions.

I have this code:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.label = data[0][0]
        self.value = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

# The actual data list contains more elements
countries = LinkedList([
    ("Ukraine",41879904),
    ("Brunei",442400),
    ("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928)
])

while countries:
    print("Country : {}, Population : {}".format(countries.label, countries.value))
    countries = countries.tail
    
print("################################")
print("# default list print completed #")
print("################################")
```

So far I have managed to get the output of the original list, however I get the following message in my code analysis:

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type
> "Optional[LinkedList]", variable has type "LinkedList")

Why does this happen, and how can I resolve the problem?

Comment: The typing error is simply because tail can be None or an instance of LInkedList. Since you don't use type annotations in your code, you might not have to worry about this.

Comment: Another possibility is to just not use the type checker. It is optional, not built in to the Python language or its requirements for correct code.

Comment: "I am also trying to figure out the best way of performing the sort without using in built functions, tried a few techniques that have just not worked out the way I would have hoped, think I am leaning towards Merge Sort" This is a separate question, which should be asked separately - we expect **one** question per post. It would probably also be off topic here. That said, mergesort is probably the easiest way to sort a linked list in N lg N, yes. You can build two sub-lists evenly by alternately adding the elements to each, so you don't have to count them in advance.

Answer (score 1):

## Reasoning

I think that the messages are displayed because...

1. the type of self.tail is implicitly interpreted as `Optional[LinkedList]`, because it can store a valid LinkedList or None

```
self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])
```

2. the type of the countries var is implicitly interpreted as LinkedList, because it is initialized to a LinkedList object

```
countries = LinkedList([...])
```

3. then, you try to assign self.tail, that is an Optional[LinkedList] var, to countries, that is a LinkedList var

```
countries = countries.tail
```

## Solution

I think that the right solution is to do is to indicate that countries is a variable of type `Optional[LinkedList]`, whenever declaring it:

```
countries: Optional[LinkedList] = LinkedList([...])
```

This is the final version of the code after the change:

```
from typing import Optional


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.label = data[0][0]
        self.value = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])


countries: Optional[LinkedList] = LinkedList([
    ("Ukraine", 41879904),
    ("Brunei", 442400),
    ("Christmas Island (Australia)", 1928)
])

while countries:
    print("Country : {}, Population : {}".format(countries.label, countries.value))
    countries = countries.tail

print("################################")
print("# default list print completed #")
print("################################")
```

Comment: As a heads-up: it isn't required to spoon-feed correct code to replace OP's exact original task; only to show complete, correct code that addresses the problem and answers the question. If the question contains a lot of extra stuff (in particular, large amounts of hard-coded data beyond what is needed to demonstrate the logic), it isn't necessary to reproduce that and give it nice formatting. The question should be edited in these cases anyway. I trimmed both OP and your answer down to three countries in the `countries` list, as that is sufficient for the list to have a head, middle and tail.

Comment: Thanks David, pretty much the same as what @samwise stated.

Now I just need to learn how to put together the sort function to print the list in population descending order after the original list print :-)

Answer (score 0):

You implicitly declared `countries` as a `LinkedList` by assigning a `LinkedList` to it, but then assign `None` to it when you reach the end of the list (`countries.tail == None` at the end of your loop).

One way to fix this would be to declare it as `Optional` up front so the typechecker knows it's okay for it to become `None` later:

```
from typing import Optional

...

countries: Optional[LinkedList] = ...
```

Note that if you do this, you can only access members of `countries` after explicitly checking that it's not `None`.  Your `while` loop handles this since it's part of the conditional, but you'll probably have to do a lot of `if countries: ...` or `assert countries is not None` later in your code if you take the route of explicitly making it `Optional`.

Another solution would be to restructure the loop so that `countries` never actually becomes `None`:

```
while True:
    print("Country : {}, Population : {}".format(countries.label, countries.value))
    if countries.tail is None:
        break
    countries = countries.tail
```

Note that if you want your code to be fully type-safe, you should annotate your `__init__` function, e.g.:

```
from typing import List, Tuple

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data: List[Tuple[str, int]]) -> None:
        self.label, self.value = data[0]
        self.tail = LinkedList(data[1:]) if data[1:] else None
```

With this type annotation the type-checker will know that `label` is a `str` and `value` is an `int`, and it will error if you pass something to your `LinkedList` constructor that isn't an appropriate list of tuples.

Comment: Hi @Samwise. Can you please help me understand the logic behind the line ```self.tail = None if len(data) == 1 else LinkedList(data[1:])```? I am little confused here, as I have never seen this approach of creating a linkedlist.

Comment: The linked list is being recursively initialized from a regular Python list.  Each node takes the first item from the list and then initializes its "tail" (note that idiomatically this is actually the "next" for this node, not the "tail" for the whole list) with the remainder of the list.  In my type-annotated version I cleaned that code up a little so it does the same thing but is slightly less confusing (IMO).

Comment: What I have always been using was initializing tail as None. And then having methods to add items to linkedlist. So, this approach is new to me. Thank you. Just one more question, this approach doesn't work when you want to add new elements to linkedlist later, right?

Comment: Thanks @Samwise, much appreciated, implemented the countries: Optional........

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin Why wouldn't it?  Nothing stops you from doing, e.g. `countries.tail = LinkedList([("Freedonia", 2658)])`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you @Samwise. Got to learn something new today.